# Restful API with NodeJs and Mysql situation with "returns" object

Tags: arrays, node.js, rest, api

I'm building a Restful API with NodeJs and Mysql, and I'm trying to return a result from to tables, using inner join, but for now I return the entire "returns" object and I want to return arrays inside arrays like a simple json object returned a noSql database.

**Current**

```
[
    {
        coluna1: 'AAAAA',
        coluna2: 'XXXXX'
    },{
        coluna1: 'AAAAA',
        coluna2: 'YYYYY'
    },{
        coluna1: 'BBBBB',
        coluna2: 'ZZZZZ'
    },
]
```

**Desired**

```
[
    {
        coluna1: 'AAAAA',
        outra_arary: [
            {
                coluna2:  'XXXXX'
            },{
                coluna2:  'YYYYY'
            }
        ]
    },{
        coluna1: 'BBBBB',
        outra_arary: [
            {
                coluna2:  'ZZZZZ'
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

That's an example of how I built my method:

```
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.connection.query(`select *
                                   from tabela1
                             inner join tabela2
                                on tabela1.id = tabela2.id;`, (error, results, fields) => {
        if (error) {
            res.send({
                "status" : 500,
                "error" : error,
                "response" : null
            });
        } else {
            res.send({
                "status" : 200,
                "error" : null,
                "response" : results
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried any methods to achieve your desired result?

Comment: Hi! I've tried to create a javascript object and populate it with this query, but I didn't succeed. I saw a library called [sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com), but I think if I use it I'll have to create an entire ORM and even get the results by joining then by this library instead of sql queries.

Answer (score 0):

Someone answered on Brazilian community of stack overflow and it worked as I needed: [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/306134/restful-api-com-nodejs-e-mysql-com-multiplas-colunas-quero-retornar-json-em-nív](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/306134/restful-api-com-nodejs-e-mysql-com-multiplas-colunas-quero-retornar-json-em-n%C3%ADv)

```
// Response from Mysql
const resultados = [
  {
      coluna1: 'AAAAA',
      coluna2: 'XXXXX'
  },{
      coluna1: 'AAAAA',
      coluna2: 'YYYYY'
  },{
      coluna1: 'BBBBB',
      coluna2: 'ZZZZZ'
  },
]

// Function that returns an array "other_array" that contains many objects with the data of the second column.
function retornaColuna(coluna) {
  const colunaFiltrada = new Array()
  resultados.forEach(valor => {
    if(valor.coluna1 == coluna)
      colunaFiltrada.push({ coluna2: valor.coluna2 })
  })
  return colunaFiltrada
}

// Create the expected structure
let resposta = new Array()
resultados.forEach(valor => {
  resposta.push({ coluna1: valor.coluna1, outra_array: retornaColuna(valor.coluna1) })
})

// Remove the duplicated columns 
resposta = resposta.filter((a) => !this[JSON.stringify(a)] && (this[JSON.stringify(a)] = true))

console.log(resposta) // It will return the expected
```